# Connected Standby eats battery when wlan is down

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, battery-life, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I use a surface pro 3 and connected standby usually works like it should: I close the cover, the surface enters standby mode, when.I open it hours later it's immediately ready and barely lost battery life.

But there is one exception: When I close the cover and move the surface out of the reception of my local wireless lan (or switch off the wireless hub), the pro3 will lose a lot of power during standby.

So as long as I stay at home it works, but when I carry the pro3 around battery life will be awful.

A sleepstuy-report confirmed, the worst offender for wasting 100% battery power is the wireless connection phase:

```
NAME TYPE % ACTIVE TIME 
Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller Networking  100% 
Connection Phase  PDC Phase  100%
```

My question: How can I fix connected standby so it does not try to connect to wlan after leaving the reach of my wireless lan?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to manually enter Airplane mode; see http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/24541-airplane-mode-off-shortcuts-create-windows-8-a.html if you want a desktop shortcut for that.

What is happening, of course, is that when away from WiFi, the tablet is continually polling fro a network, possibly increasing signal strength to reach one. The same thing happens to cell phones out of reach of a tower.

Comment: That way I'd have to remember to enter airplain mode every time when the Surface might leave the hotspot - which I don't know in advance.
I'd rather disable connected standby fully, if there is a way.